# How to make hollows with css

Tags: html, css, card

I am trying to make some narrows on my card element. What I am trying to achieve is:

[image]

My problem is I cannot make the hollows on the top and down.

So with margin: 20px 0, I tried to make these hollows but I am not successfull and my card is fully straight. Can you help me about this?

```css
.card {
position: relative;
    display: flex;
    min-width: 0;
height: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border-radius: .25rem;
  border: none;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  flex-direction: initial;
}

.sold-tickets-image {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 35px;
}

.rip {
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAACCAYAAAB7Xa1eAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAYdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuOWwzfk4AAAAaSURBVBhXY5g7f97/2XPn/AcCBmSMQ+I/AwB2eyNBlrqzUQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
  background-size: 4px 2px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

.rip:before,
.rip:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  border-right-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.rip:before {
  //left: -10px;
}

.rip:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate( 315deg);
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="sold-tickets-actions">
    <img class="sold-tickets-image" :src="image" alt="Sold Ticket" />
  </div>

  <div class="rip"></div>
  <div class="sold-tickets-actions">
    <img class="sold-tickets-image" :src="image" alt="Sold Ticket" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51365042/8620333

Comment: also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67383502/8620333 and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67345816/8620333

Comment: I think [masking](https://web.dev/css-masking/) could help you

Comment: What is this construct? `:src="image" `

Comment: @mplungjan Probably some kind of VueJS binding directive

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I am actually successful in making them horizontal but not vertical

Comment: Can the HTML structure change?

Comment: @Levi Cole yes it can change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```css
/*
* Prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io
* PostCSS: v8.3.6,
* Autoprefixer: v10.3.1
* Browsers: last 4 version
*/

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
          filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}

.rip {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex-positive: 0;
          flex-grow: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-size: 2px 4px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient( circle at center top, transparent 15px, black 16px) top,
    radial-gradient( circle at center bottom, transparent 15px, black 16px) bottom;
          mask:
    radial-gradient( circle at center top, transparent 15px, black 16px) top,
    radial-gradient( circle at center bottom, transparent 15px, black 16px) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size:100% 50%;
          mask-size:100% 50%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
          mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.sold-tickets-actions {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-negative: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
}

img.sold-tickets-image {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="sold-tickets-actions">
    <img class="sold-tickets-image" :src="image" alt="Sold Ticket" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="rip"></div>
  
  <div class="sold-tickets-actions">
    <img class="sold-tickets-image" :src="image" alt="Sold Ticket" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

---

The above example only does the center of the tickets, to apply the styles to all corners, you can do the following...

```css
/*
* Prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io
* PostCSS: v8.3.6,
* Autoprefixer: v10.3.1
* Browsers: last 4 version
*/

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
          filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}

.sold-tickets-actions {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-negative: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
}

.sold-tickets-actions:before,
.sold-tickets-actions:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.sold-tickets-actions:before {
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient( circle at left top, transparent 15px, black 16px) top,
    radial-gradient( circle at left bottom, transparent 15px, black 16px) bottom;
          mask:
    radial-gradient( circle at left top, transparent 15px, black 16px) top,
    radial-gradient( circle at left bottom, transparent 15px, black 16px) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 50%;
          mask-size: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
          mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-left: 1px dashed #333;
}

.sold-tickets-actions:after {
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient( circle at right top, transparent 15px, black 16px) top,
    radial-gradient( circle at right bottom, transparent 15px, black 16px) bottom;
          mask:
    radial-gradient( circle at right top, transparent 15px, black 16px) top,
    radial-gradient( circle at right bottom, transparent 15px, black 16px) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 50%;
          mask-size: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
          mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-right: 1px dashed #333;
}

.sold-tickets-inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-negative: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
}

img.sold-tickets-image {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="sold-tickets-actions">
    <div class="sold-tickets-inner">
      <img class="sold-tickets-image" :src="image" alt="Sold Ticket" />
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="sold-tickets-actions">
    <div class="sold-tickets-inner">
      <img class="sold-tickets-image" :src="image" alt="Sold Ticket" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what I am trying to achieve is to have holes at the top and bottom.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include another approach and css prefixes for better browser support.